# Show a div in between flex items

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm creating a page that is populated with `<div>` elements. The container containing this div has `display: flex;`. So the items wrap automaticaly to several rows. Now I want to click on an item so it would open another `<div>` with info about the selected item. But this info div should come under the row that contains the selected div and with full width of the container.

I don't know how to make this work.
I made a simple JsFiddle to start with: https://jsfiddle.net/44j4jnq4/3/

I'm getting the click event and dynamiccaly adding the dinfo div with Angular.
My question is mostly about how to style it so it wouldn't mess with the flex items and have a width of the container.

Also I have this image to visualize what I'm going for.

[image]

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: With angular you need to find the last item on the selected items row, inject the element after it and set its `flex-basis` to `100%`. Done like that, the injected element will participate in the layout as your drawing show, filling the width of the container on a row of its own.

Comment: @LGSon But how do I get the latest flex item on a row. And would this work if the info box is open and I resize the page, so the last element would flip over the next row? I rather see something more CSS based, if possible, then plain calculating it with Angualr.

Comment: Since there is no CSS that will _know_ which element is last and be able to keep the injected one after that, the closest is to inject it after the clicked, and with the drawing as a sample, you would get this: https://jsfiddle.net/44j4jnq4/4/

Comment: If to click on the second item, you get this https://jsfiddle.net/44j4jnq4/5/ ... and as you can see they won't even out the items per row. To overcome that you need a script that find the last on the row and inject it after it. You will also need to use the resize event and keep track on line breaks and adjust the injected item accordingly

Comment: @LGSon Instead of injecting a new `div` between two rows, I was looking to expand the height of the clicked `div`and add the infobox to that div. Like in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44j4jnq4/7/) But I don't now how to make it the width of the container. I guess this way it is always connected to the right div.

Comment: CSS Grid might be able to do this, so I added it to your tags so the guys who know this will find your question.

Comment: With inject into the clicked element, if you resize that fiddle you see you get the same issue with not evening the rows out. If CSS Grid can't do this, you will need either what I showed in my first sample or you need a script

Comment: There might be one way, using media query's, if your elements can have a fixed width and if not too many elements (or else it gets messy with all the css it would take). Can they have fixed width and how many will there be?

Comment: @LGSon They have a fixed width and height. But the exact amount can vary between a couple to a lot (1-500+).

Comment: I also added `angular` to the tags list. You'll have to wait and see if someone with CSS Grid or Angular skills have a good solution for you

Comment: I was just about to say... .this is the perfect use for CSS Grid. Browser support is not great though, and some properties are difficult / impossible to animate with CSS grid

Comment: I do something very similar in one of my apps, but I hide the rest of the elements except one row on the bottom. So it may be easier than your use case. But i'm interested in using something like this in the future, so I will try to work up a solution. To clarify: your boxes won't always be a certain width or height, and won't always have a certain number of rows / columns right?

Comment: @diopside Actually I wan't my boxes a fixed width and height. Because of the content it contains. The number of rows depends of the number of items wich can go high. The number of items on a row depends on the width of the parent container. This should be responsive. So If the container shrinks, less items will fit on a single row. I don't mind a empty gap at the right of the rows. If a solution is available for items with a variable row, I think it could be changed to a fixed wifth and height aswell. So both are good.

Comment: Ok cool - fixed box size makes this slightly easier...

Comment: You could create a single div to contain additional info and inject corresponding info into it. For the correct positioning you could try play with the order property. I've been trying but can't get the other divs to wrap -- https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/quh8srxk/3/  -- just a thought

Comment: @ovokuro This can be done using media query, though since it can be up to 500 elements, it will create too much CSS to make a reasonable solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I slightly modified the html by wrapping the `.item` inside a `.item-container` to achieve the desired styling.

Also I am using `:after` element to show the info from the `title` of `.infobox`.

To fill the width I've added a div with fixed height and an absolutely positioned `:after` which is referenced to `.container` in order to take full width, click on the `.item` to see the info, please check this out.

```js
$('.container').click(function(e){
 if(!$(e.target).next().hasClass('show')){
   $('.item-container .show').removeClass('show');
   $(e.target).next().addClass('show');
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.infobox {
  height: 110px;
  display: none;
}
.infobox.show{
  display: block;
}
.infobox.show:after{
    content: attr(title);
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 1</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 1 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">Item 2</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 2 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 3</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 3 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 4</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 4 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 5</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 5 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 6</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 6 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 7</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 7 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 8</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 8 info"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Without using `:after` element, try this

```js
$('.container').click(function(e){
 if(!$(e.target).next().hasClass('show')){
   $('.item-container .show').removeClass('show');
   $(e.target).next().addClass('show');
   $(e.target).next().html('<div class="content"><h4>'+$(e.target).next().attr('title')+'</h4><img style="width:50px" src="https://olinuris.library.cornell.edu/sites/default/files/equipment/Draper%2050x50%20Template_1.jpg" /><button>Press</button></div>')
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.infobox {
  height: 160px;
  display: none;
}
.infobox.show{
  display: block;
}
.infobox .content{
    height: 150px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 1</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 1 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">Item 2</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 2 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="infobox" title="Item 3 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 4</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 4 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 5</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 5 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 6</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 6 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 7</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 7 info"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container"> 
      <div class="item">Item 8</div><div class="infobox" title="Item 8 info"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The downside is that the info won't push the elements coming after it since absolute positioning is used

Comment: If you inspect u can see `.infobox` is not positioned only the `:after` element is positioned. since the parent is relative to the `.item` it'll push the content, only limitation is we've to set a particular height to the `.infobox` which isn't a problem if the info is not dynamic.

Comment: Which was what I meant when saying _info won't push the elements coming after_. This solution need a fixed height set on the info, which might be perfectly fine, being a CSS only solution

Comment: This solution looks promising, I guess I can remove the 'hidden' infoboxes with an ngIf in Angular. I'll give it a try and see how it turns ot.

Comment: @SaravananI I implemented this solution, but I'm not happy with the way the content is set through `content`. I'm not aware of any possibilty to add complex html, like images links, text and buttons this way.

Comment: In that case instead of `:after` add a div inside .infobox and apply the same stylings of the `:after` element

Comment: @SaravananI I tested your updated code and it works. So I guess this is solved. Thank you, and all the others for your help.